# PHP Compare items in an array

Tags: php

I have an array in PHP.
My array is the above:

```
| Student First Name   |Student Last Name   | Age |Disability|
| Student_First_Name_1 |Student_Last_Name_1 | 30  | 1        |
| Student_First_Name_2 |Student_Last_Name_2 | 28  | 0        |
| Student_First_Name_3 |Student_Last_Name_3 | 21  | 0        |
| Student_First_Name_4 |Student_Last_Name_4 | 20  | 1        |
```

and I want from this array to compare the entries and make groups and save them to database.
So the student_1 with entry 1 will be grouped with the Student_4 with entry 1 and the Student_2 with the Student_3.

My code is the above:

```
$count=count($TempSelected);
for($i=1,$j=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    if($TempSelected[$j]['disability']==$TempSelected[$i]['disability']){
        if( abs($TempSelected[$j]['age']-$TempSelected[$i]['age']) <= 23 ){
            $Student1 = $TempSelected[$j]['first_name'].' '.$TempSelected[$j]['last_name'];
            $Student2 = $TempSelected[$i]['first_name'].' '.$TempSelected[$i]['last_name'];
            unset($TempSelected[$i]);
            unset($TempSelected[$j]);
            $FirstEntry = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM ".$TableName." WHERE Checked = 0 LIMIT 1");
            $FirstEntry->execute();
            $id = $FirstEntry->fetchColumn();
            $data = [
                'student_1' => $Student1,
                'student_2' => $Student2,
                'Checked' => 1,
                'id' => $id,
                ];
            $AddStudent = $conn->prepare("UPDATE ".$TableName." SET student_1=:student_1, student_2=:student_2, Checked=:Checked WHERE id=:id");
            $AddStudent->execute($data);
        }
    }
    $count=count($TempSelected);
}
```

But it only make a group and stops.

I want to stops when it make all the groups not only 1.

Can you help me?

I edit my array above and I entered exactly what I have in the array

Comment: var_dump your $TempSelected an print it to description please

Comment: Your array's `disability` key has value `0` and `1`?

Comment: You never increment `$j`. You need nested loops.

Comment: Please provide array format as told by @MohammedYassineCHABLI echo "<pre>"; var_dump($TempSelected ); echo "</pre>";

Comment: You don't need to prepare the statement every time through the loop. Prepare it once, then execute it in the loop.

Comment: You can also use a `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` statement so you don't have to do two queries.

Comment: But in this case you don't even need a join, since you're updating the same table. Just do `UPDATE ... WHERE checked = 0 LIMIT 1`.

Comment: You are `unset`ing various elements and at the end your resetting `$count` to the new `count()` of the elements in the array.  BUT `$i` (which is the control test against `$count`) is just left as it is.

Comment: If you need to group the students with the same value of `Disability`, then it would help if you had an `order by Disability` clause when selecting the data.  This means they will be sequential in the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested loops to compare all the pairs of elements. Your code increments `$i`, but `$j` is always `0`, so you're only comparing with the first student.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this one. It's worked. But I have one small problem.
When I have 5 students in my array, it doesn't removes the 2 ready groups, but instead the last one grouped with the other 2.

Comment: Note sure I understand. But I don't think your code works when you have an odd number of students. it puts them into the database in pairs, so if there's an odd number there's no one for it to be paired with.